# Como criar uma modal com remote content no Semantic-UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

Com o Bootstrap eu sei que é possível criar uma modal com conteúdo remoto da seguinte forma:

```html
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="exemplo.html" data-target="#exemplo">Exemplo</a></li>
```

Há algo parecido no Semantic ui? A documentação oficial apenas ensina como criar da seguinte forma:

```javascript
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

E isso não ajuda muito pois minha modal é outra página, e não uma *div* com a *class **ui modal***, como no exemplo da documentação

Comment: Acho que não dá, o que dá é fazer um modal para várias páginas, e carregar um conteúdo dinamico dentro do modal. Se ainda estiver com dúvida eu posso te ajudar.